# Layout in ExtJs 4.1

Tags: javascript, extjs, layout, multiple-columns, extjs4.2

Hy,
this is my first question so please be nice to me. :D

Ok here is my question i have a problem with the layout in ExtJs.

basically i want a layout like:

```random
+--------+-----------------+-----------------+-------------------+
|   B    |   TF            |          B      |   TF              |
|--------|--------+--------|-----------------+-------------------+-------------+
|   B    |   TF   |   B    |         B       |    TF             |      B      |
+--------+--------+--------+-----------------+-------------------+-------------+
```

where B stands for `Ext.Button` and TF for `Ext.form.TextField`

an those Buttons and TextFields are in a

```js
new Ext.Panel({
  layout : {
    type : 'table',
    columns : 10
  }
});
```

I tried it with a colspan but it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another variant with the table layout, only downside is that you have to specify the width of your column otherwise the columns will be sized according to their content...

```
var w = 50;
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    title: 'Table Layout',
    layout: {
        type: 'table',
        // The total column count must be specified here
        columns: 10
    },
    defaults: {
        // applied to each contained panel
        bodyStyle: 'padding:20px',
        margin: 5,
        width: w
    },
    items: [{
        xtype: "button",
        text: "1_1",
        colspan: 1
    }, {
        xtype: "textfield",
        value: "1_2",
        colspan: 2,
        width: 2 * w
    }, {
        xtype: "button",
        text: "1_3",
        colspan: 3,
        width: 3 * w
    }, {
        xtype: "textfield",
        value: "1_4",
        colspan: 2,
        width: 2 * w
    }, {
        xtype: 'component',
        html: '',
        colspan: 2,
        width: 2 * w
    }, {
        xtype: "button",
        text: "2_1",
        colspan: 1
    }, {
        xtype: "textfield",
        value: "2_2",
        colspan: 1
    }, {
        xtype: "button",
        text: "2_3",
        colspan: 1
    }, {
        xtype: "button",
        text: "2_4",
        colspan: 3,
        width: 3 * w
    }, {
        xtype: "textfield",
        value: "2_5",
        colspan: 2,
        width: 2 * w
    }, {
        xtype: "button",
        text: "2_6",
        colspan: 2,
        width: 2 * w
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Comment: this actually fits more what i already made ;D thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this with the [hbox](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.HBox) and the [vbox](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.VBox) layout. Important is the [flex](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Box-cfg-flex) property.

Example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/m05

```
Ext.create("Ext.Panel", {
    width : 800,
    height : 600,

    layout : {
        type : "vbox",
        align : "stretch"
    },

    items : [{
            xtype : "container",
            layout : "hbox",
            margin : "0 0 5 0",
            items : [{
                    xtype : "button",
                    text : "1_1",
                    flex : 1,
                    margin : "0 5 0 0"
                }, {
                    xtype : "textfield",
                    value : "1_2",
                    flex : 2,
                    margin : "0 5 0 0"
                }, {
                    xtype : "button",
                    text : "1_3",
                    flex : 2,
                    margin : "0 5 0 0"
                }, {
                    xtype : "textfield",
                    value : "1_4",
                    flex : 2,
                    margin : "0 5 0 0"
                }, {
                    xtype : "container",
                    flex : 2
                }
            ]
        }, {
            xtype : "container",
            layout : "hbox",
            items : [{
                    xtype : "button",
                    text : "2_1",
                    flex : 1,
                    margin : "0 5 0 0"
                }, {
                    xtype : "container",
                    flex : 2,
                    margin : "0 5 0 0",
                    layout : "hbox",
                    items : [{
                            xtype : "textfield",
                            value : "2_2",
                            flex : 1,
                            margin : "0 5 0 0"
                        }, {
                            xtype : "button",
                            text : "2_3",
                            flex : 1
                        }
                    ]
                }, {
                    xtype : "button",
                    text : "2_4",
                    flex : 2,
                    margin : "0 5 0 0"
                }, {
                    xtype : "textfield",
                    value : "2_5",
                    flex : 2,
                    margin : "0 5 0 0"
                }, {
                    xtype : "button",
                    text : "2_6",
                    flex : 2
                }
            ]
        }
    ],

    renderTo : Ext.getBody()
});
```

Comment: is there a possibility to make spaces between buttons and TextFields?

Comment: Of course. You can do this with margin, but if you use hbox I recommend to set another nested container for the "colspan" cell. This is that ExtJS can calculate the accurate width. I edited my example.